# Why am i getting the database error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser] ] has been closed()

Tags: java, c3p0

I am getting the below error when I deployed the application to another environment. It is working fine in local.

> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser] ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.

Can somebody help on this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are connecting to the correct db and the database is up and running?
If you explicitly close a c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource you cannot revive it. Any chance you wanted to reset it?

Comment: Yes I am connecting to the correct db and it is up and running

Comment: Got it fixed :) There we mismatch in the jar version in the server and the app lib